# Not able to increase the Header size in karaf Jetty

Tags: rest, jetty, embedded-jetty, apache-karaf

I am running a REST API on karaf Jetty, The REST service uses JWT tokens for security. When sending a request to the service, the server is complaining that the header is to large. The following exception is thrown (Header is too large >8192).

```
2017-04-28 10:38:35,461 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | URI --> SPACE2
2017-04-28 10:38:35,461 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | SPACE2 --> REQUEST_VERSION
2017-04-28 10:38:35,461 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | REQUEST_VERSION --> HEADER
2017-04-28 10:38:35,461 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2017-04-28 10:38:35,461 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2017-04-28 10:38:35,464 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | ChannelEndPoint                  | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | filled 1887 SelectChannelEndPoint@269ccd27{/10.30.8.29:14179<->8181,Open,in,out,-,-,4/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2017-04-28 10:38:35,464 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | parseNext s=HEADER_IN_VALUE HeapByteBuffer@77e9f1ca[p=0,l=1887,c=8192,r=1887]={<<<NSVhfTU5HUl9HRVRf...0.8.29:8181\r\n\r\n>>>JPTEVfVk1XQVJFX01...T0xFX1NFUlZJQ0V}
2017-04-28 10:38:35,464 | WARN  | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Header is too large >8192
2017-04-28 10:38:35,465 | WARN  | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | badMessage: 413 for HttpChannelOverHttp@548aa950{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
2017-04-28 10:38:35,465 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | 
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser$BadMessageException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseHeaders(HttpParser.java:932)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.http:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1256)[97:org.eclipse.jetty.http:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:250)[106:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[98:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[109:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[109:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_101]
2017-04-28 10:38:35,465 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpParser                       | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | HEADER_IN_VALUE --> CLOSED
2017-04-28 10:38:35,465 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpChannelState                 | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | HttpChannelState@462fabb8{s=IDLE i=true a=null} handling IDLE
2017-04-28 10:38:35,465 | DEBUG | tp1430443284-800 | HttpConnection                   | 109 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnect
```

I tried increasing the header size property for JETTY using the following configuration on the  jetty.xml. However jetty keeps complaining about the header size (Header is too large >8192) with the same exception after the change. For some reason JETTY is not increasing the header size with this configuration, Can somebody shed some light  on how to fix this problem? thanks

```
<Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host">
                    <Property name="jetty.host" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="port">
                    <Property name="jetty.port" default="8181" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
                <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
                <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
                <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
                <Set name="requestHeaderSize">32768</Set>
                <Set name="headerCacheSize">32768</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
```

After some research I found a post that pointed to the following configuration change on jetty.xml, This is using SSL However the header size still not changing in jetty, I mam getting the same error.

```
<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
    <Set name="securePort">
        <Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
    <Set name="requestHeaderSize">32768</Set>
    <Set name="responseHeaderSize">32768</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
    <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
</New>
```

Comment: Jetty 9.2.10.v20150310 does not have a `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector`.  That configuration should have made your startup completely fail.  Your configuration wasn't used, perhaps karaf has a different way to configure itself?

Comment: Be careful in increasing that limit, as many http intermediaries (proxies, gateways, load balancers, layer 7 routers) do not function properly with large HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks for  the advice, I will take in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

After many days of research I found a solution, I found the solution in the following URL

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/security_guide/webconsole

This solution increases the size of the request header but uses HTTPS.

Comment: Afaik karaf uses pax web to config the underlaying jetty, here you can find the official docs: http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/6.x/User-Guide.html#advanced-jetty-configuration

We tried to enable gzip using this approach, and did not succeed.